# Ford Fiesta SE starter replacement

Tags: starter

the starter on my Ford Fiesta SE went out and I'm doing some DIY to replace it. I replaced my starter on my old 96 Accord once before, so I figured this would be no problem. I'm almost there, but there is one bolt I can't seem to get to. I don't see a way to access it under the car and from the top there is some curved metal piece (pictured) blocking access. I've tried to loosen the bolts with no luck and can't seem to find the right size socket. 10mm is too big and 9 is too small. I've tried every other size close to it with no luck. Any help/advice anyone can offer?

[image: curved piece blocking 3rd starter bolt]

Comment: Welcome.  Which year fiesta and which engine is does it have?

Comment: Try using a 10mm 6-point socket. It provides a tighter fit than 12-point. You can also try covering the bolt in 1-4 layers of aluminum foil before forcing the socket onto it.